# How to read a file using javax.lang.model?

Tags: java, code-generation

I see lot of references to javax.lang.model as being the api for parsing java files and it seems it'll suffice for what I want to do. But I can't find any examples of using the classes in it starting with opening a .java file. The only vague reference I have found are about writing a compiler plugin and invoking your code using javac.

Is that the only way to use this api? Isn't it possible to simply open a file and get the instances of classes from javax.lang.model.element with your own main()? Would anyone be able to point me to working examples of this nature?

Answer (score 3):

The javax.lang.model, javax.lang.model.element, javax.lang.model.element.type, and javax.model.element.util packages are intended for use in annotation processors (javax.annotation.processing.Processor), which are the compiler plug-ins that you mentioned.  There is a compiler API that you can use to compile and analyze classes at run-time.  You can use javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() which returns a javax.tools.JavaCompiler class.  It has an interface to compile .java files and to run annotation processors against them.  For more information check out [JavaCompiler#getTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)